How to Automatically Extract Data from VICIdial Using API Calls for Power BI Integration?
I am currently working on a project where I need to extract daily reports from VICIdial to load into Power BI.
I only have access to the VICIdial admin interface and not the underlying database.
I want to automate the data extraction process daily.
I am particularly interested in the Report section of VICIdial.
I would like to specify the date for the report extraction
(ideally for the current day)
I am not clear on how to format the API request, including the necessary parameters.
I need guidance on handling the API response and transforming the data for use in Power BI.
Any suggestions on how to test my API calls without affecting existing VICIdial data
would be appreciated.
I am using Python for scripting and plan to use the requests library for making API calls.
I would like to know if there are best practices for integrating the data extraction process with Power BI.
Can someone provide an example of how to structure the API request for extracting daily reports?
What are the best practices for transforming the API response for Power BI?
Are there any resources or tutorials that you recommend for working with VICIdial APIs?
Any help or direction on this would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance!
I have researched the VICIdial API and found documentation on available endpoints,
but I am unsure how to structure my API calls correctly.


Please extract the data from slave DB to Power BI
Create one user with API access
vicidial should have documentation for agent and non-agent api
sometimes we may need to create one, still depends on what you wanna achieve.

